# Return cells content from range

Tags: excel, vba

Yesterday I learned here how to copy a row to a second sheet.

```
Sub maJolieProcedure(Texte As String)
    With Worksheets("employes").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(what:=Texte)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Ok"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nok"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

To respect the formatting of the second sheet, I want to copy and paste the contents of each cell one by one.

I can identify the line number. However, I can't figure out how the Range object can return each cell one by one. For example, C3 content if `Rows = 3`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You received 2 answers and selected neither. That doesn't go for diplomacy around here because the next fellow to look for answers won't benefit from the work you did. Please provide guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to paste the formatting from one range to another paste values only.

```
Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy
Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

That's the same for all ranges, whether 1 cell or a million. The Copy process copies the subject to memory as one block. Any parsing must be done before the Copy instruction. An alternative is to read a range into an array.

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Value
```

This will create a 3D array of 1 row and about 16000 columns. You might decide to limit your enthusiasm to only what you need.

```
With Worksheets("employees")
    Arr = .Range(.Cells(firstAddress, 1), .Cells(firstAddress, .Columns.Count).End)xlToLeft)).Value
End With
```

Pay attention to the leading periods within the With statement. Each such period stands for the object mentioned in the With statement.

Comment: Thanks. I had gone too far...  I understood by reading your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to respect the formating of the second sheet, you don't need to loose time copying cell by cell.

It is more effective to do a paste special, like you do with the mouse:

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

works very well also with bigger ranges if you need:

```
Range("A1:A12").Copy
Range("B1:B12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

or even

```
Range("A1:A12").Copy
Range("D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

If your goal is to really access all cell of a range individually , you just iterate on the range. For example:

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A12")
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 2
Next cell
```

Comment: @skraft I solved the problem by examining the two answers. I wanted to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. :) Thanks.